# Duplicate the content of the element in a XML file using JAVA

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Consider this is the xml file

```
<rpc>
<edit-config>
<config>
<element>
<name> user%index%</name>
<place> wakanda </palce>
<count> number%index%</count>
</element>
</config>
</edit-config>
</rpc>
```

I need the element attribute alone to be duplicated 5 times where i replace %index% with value 1 to 5, so that output looks something like below, i need java code for the same Please help me.

```
<rpc>
<edit-config>
<config>
<element>
<name> user1</name>
<place> wakanda </palce>
<count> number1</count>
</element>
<element>
<name> user2</name>
<place> wakanda </palce>
<count> number2</count>
</element>
<element>
<name> user3</name>
<place> wakanda </palce>
<count> number3</count>
</element>
<element>
<name> user4</name>
<place> wakanda </palce>
<count> number4</count>
</element>
<element>
<name> user5</name>
<place> wakanda </palce>
<count> number5</count>
</element>
</config>
</edit-config>
</rpc>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that one of the easiest ways to do this is by creating a simple for loop where you
copy the content multiple times and use the String.replace method to replace "%index%" with your desired value.

[String.replace Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation before. I have tidied up my previous work and put it on github as an external jar/open source. https://github.com/tataelm/XmlNodeCloner

**How to use it?**

```
XmlNodeCloner xmlNodeCloner = new XmlNodeCloner("src/input.xml", "element", 2);
xmlNodeCloner.setIfCloneLatestOrCertain(true);
xmlNodeCloner.selectCloningElementByTagValue("name", "user1");
xmlNodeCloner.addXmlTagsToEnumerate("name","count");    
xmlNodeCloner.setmEnumeratorStyle(EnumeratorStyle.DEFAULT);
xmlNodeCloner.isAlreadyIterated(true);
xmlNodeCloner.runCloner();
```

Create an instance of XmlNodeCloner with 3 parameters.

1. xmlPath: give the path to your xml file
2. elementName: give the element name you want to clone. In your case: "element"
3. cloneCount: is an integer value. How many clones you want to have from that element

If you want to clone a certain node, make sure you call following methods. By default, it is cloning the latest node

```
xmlNodeCloner.setIfCloneLatestOrCertain(true);
xmlNodeCloner.selectCloningElementByTagValue("name", "user1");
```

If you want to enumerate certain nodes, call following methods. Parameters are the nodes' name you want to enumerate

```
xmlNodeCloner.addXmlTagsToEnumerate("name","count");    
xmlNodeCloner.setmEnumeratorStyle(EnumeratorStyle.DEFAULT);
```

If the node you want to clone/duplicate already iterated once, it will have iteration number. Call this following method if you want to continue from previous iteration

```
xmlNodeCloner.isAlreadyIterated(true);
```

There are 5 different enumeration style, defined in enum. You can call these styles by the following.

```
xmlNodeCloner.setmEnumeratorStyle(EnumeratorStyle.DEFAULT);

public enum EnumeratorStyle {
    DEFAULT, DASH, SPACE_DASH_SPACE, UNDERSCORE, SPACE_UNDERSCORE_SPACE
}
```